# Why does gawk asort()'s output not in order?

Tags: awk

I tried this `gawk` cmd:

```
# gawk 'BEGIN{
> var["a"] = 1
> var["g"] = 2
> var["m"] = 3
> var["u"] = 4
> asort(var, test)
> for (i in test)
> print "Index:",i," - value:",test[i]
> }'
```

and will get the following output:

> Index: 4  - value: 4
>
> Index: 1  - value: 1
>
> Index: 2  - value: 2
>
> Index: 3  - value: 3

so I wonder why the output isn't in order like:

> Index: 1
>
> Index: 2
>
> ...

becuz this is the right sequence for the array's value

Comment: Think about in what order the keys are returned from `test` into `i` in the `for` loop.

Comment: How exactly are you looking to sort the array? The array keys here are `a`, `g`, `m`, `u`, while the values are 1 to 4 in order, so in a way it seems like the keys are the more interesting ones. Yet, if you run `asort()` on the array, the keys are lost. Which is why you only see 1 to 4 in the result, not `agmu`.

Comment: @ilkkachu I am reading a book about Shell Scripting now and it just show me this code to explain the asort() and asorti() built-in function. That's the reason LOL

Comment: @admin, can you tell which book? physical or online?

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu, the book's name is "Linux® Command Line and Shell Scripting BIBLE" and mine is a PDF version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for (var in array)` does not guarantee an order in which the elements of array is accessed.

The loop will iterate over each element as it is stored in memory, but if during the storing on the next element, awk decided to plug some hole in the memory - you would have a 'strange' order.

BTW, it is described in the official documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html#index-for-statement-1

So if you want a guaranteed sorted array, you would have to use something like:

```
element_count = asort(var, test)
for (i=1; i<=element_count; i++)
   print "Index:",i," - value:",test[i]
```

Comment: Yes, I've read the GNU official doc(the **Array Intro** part) and it said "The pairs are shown in jumbled order because their order is irrelevant". But your example is more clear, so the `for in ARRAY` will not necessarily output the array according to its index.

Comment: Although for gawk 4.0 up (now widespread) the next page after (and linked from) that page describes using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to get one of several sorted orders.

Answer (score 0):

I think `asort()` lends itself better to arrays indexed by integers, since it replaces the indexes with 1 to *n*, destroying the original indexes. (As you saw in your case, the indexes `a`, `g`, `m`, `u` were lost.)

So, with an integer-indexed array:

```
$ cat sort.awk
BEGIN {
    printf("original:\n");
    n = split("hello and bye", a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, a[i])
    }
    printf("sorted:\n");
    n = asort(a, b);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, b[i])
    }
}

$ awk -f sort
original:
1 hello
2 and
3 bye
sorted:
1 and
2 bye
3 hello
```

If your indexes themselves contain data, you might want `asorti()` instead;
it creates a new array with the original keys as values, and indexed from 1 up so that the keys are in order:

```
$ cat sort2.awk
BEGIN {
    d["foo"]=11;
    d["bar"]=22;
    d["doo"]=33;
    n = asorti(d, p);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %s\n", i, p[i], d[p[i]])
    }
}
$ awk -f sort2.awk
1 bar 22
2 doo 33
3 foo 11
```

In both cases, the issue described in [White Owl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721323/170373) about iterating over the array needs to be taken into consideration.